# How to read an HTML file and replace with our characters

Tags: c#

I have an HTML file template which is used for mailing purpose here in the template.

```
Hi XXX,
Thanks for joing in the Club, your ClubcardNo is : XXXXX

Thanks
```

Here now in the code I need to replace this XXXX with name and clubcard no:

```
name:Kiran
clubcard no: 23453
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this as a string value. (ie you [read it in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) as a string from the file) then you can just do

```
String s = s.Replace("XXXXX", "23453");
```

Where s is the string that you retrieved from the file and the number is an example. I'm sure you won't hardcode them like that.

Answer (score 5):

You can mark your special words. For example:

Your code in HTML file:

```
<p>  welcome #Name #Family </p>
```

In C# use this code:

```
StreamReader sr =new StreamReader("Path of your file");
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
s.Replace("#name","123456").Replace("#Family","123456");
sr.Close();}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str=@"Hi XXX,
                Thanks for joing in the Club, your ClubcardNo is : XXXXX

                Thanks";

str.Replace("XXXXX","23453").Replace("XXX","Kiran");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "XXX", "Kiran");
```

where input is your html template as a string.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest you try using a templating engine like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) instead. It will give you more flexibility and robustness, while still being simple to use.